# Locking down a SQL Server that can be connected into remotely

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, security, sql-server-2008

If a SQL Server is has remote access open, what steps should one take to lock it down?

1. strong password
2. restrict the user to the database

Anything else?

Should I disable the sa account?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things off the top of my head...

- Change the TCP port number SQL server is listening on.
- If client connections to sql server come from a small number of known sites, use a firewall to accept connections only from a those clients' IPs.
- Rename the sa account?

Another idea is to not publicly expose the SQL server. Instead, use an encrypted SSH or VPN tunnel to connect to it.